# Add multiple custom columns to WooCommerce "My account" orders table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am trying to add a few columns to the WooCommerce > my account > orders page.

So far the code below adds more than one column but the content of the columns are not showing, where I'm I getting it wrong?

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'add_account_orders_column', 10, 1 );
function add_account_orders_column( $columns ){
    
     unset($columns['order-total']);
   $columns['custom-column'] = __( 'New Column', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns['custom-column2'] = __( 'New Column 2', 'woocommerce' );

    return $columns;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom-column', 'add_account_orders_column_rows' );
function add_account_orders_column_rows( $order ) {
    // Example with a custom field

    if( $columns == 'custom-column' ) {

        echo 'Hello';

    }

    if( $columns == 'custom-column2' ) {

        echo 'Hello 2';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `woocommerce_account_orders_columns` filter hook allows us to add 1 or more columns

```php
// Add new column(s) to the "My Orders" table in the account.
function filter_woocommerce_account_orders_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['custom-column'] = __( 'New Column 1', 'woocommerce' );
    $columns['custom-column2'] = __( 'New Column 2', 'woocommerce' );

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'filter_woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 10, 1 );
```

---

However, adding content per column is done via the `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_{$column_id}` action hook.

So `{$column_id}` need to be replaced by the column key slug (`custom-column` or `custom-column2`) in this particular case.
It is therefore not necessary to determine the correct column in the callback function via an if condition

So you get:

```php
// Adds data to the custom column in "My Account > Orders"
function action_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom_column( $order ) {    
    echo 'New Column 1';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom-column', 'action_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom_column', 10, 1 );

// Adds data to the custom column in "My Account > Orders"
function action_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom_column2( $order ) {    
    echo 'New Column 2';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom-column2', 'action_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom_column2', 10, 1 );
```